Help proving the $(\forall)$-introduction rule written in terms of $\exists$ in natural deduction
I'm trying to prove the $(\forall)$-introduction rule in Natural Deduction (written in terms of $\exists$):
$$\frac{\phi [t/x]}{\neg\exists x\neg\phi} \ \ \ \ \begin{matrix}\text{ given that $t$ does not appear in $\phi$ nor in any}\\ \text{ undischarged assumption in the proof of $\phi[t/x]$}\end{matrix}$$
I believe the proof should go something like so:

$1.\ \phi[t/x]$

$2.\ \exists x\neg\phi \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ (discharged assumption)

$3.\ \neg\phi[t/x]  \ \ \ \ \ \ $ (discharged assumption)
$4.\ \psi\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ (?)


$5.\ \psi\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  $ ($\exists$-elimination with (2) and (4))
$-$
$6.\ \exists \neg \phi \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ (discharged assumption)
$7.\ \phi[t/x]\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ (1)
$8.\ \neg\psi\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ (?)


$9.\ \neg\exists\neg\phi\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ ($\neg$ introduction with (5) and (8))

The main problem is of course that I do not know what $\psi$ is supposed to be. Intuitively, it should be the statement $\neg\phi[t/x]$, but the $\exists$-elminitation rules requires that $t$ does not appear in $\psi$.

What are the exact rules you are working with?  Does your system use a contradiction symbol $\bot$? How is $\neg$ Intro defined?

@Bram28 I should have specified: the rules I'm allowed to use can be found in pages 3 and 4 of his guide: https://users.ox.ac.uk/~logicman/carr/NDpack.pdf. I hope you can forgive me for not writing them out explicitly.

Natural deduction is a terrible formalism. You should learn to think with sequents and to keep track of variables correctly.

@NaïmFavier What? Natural Deduction is just a model of how humans normally reason. No one reasons like sequent calculus, even though it’s useful as a formalism.

@PW_246 that is exactly why it's a terrible formalism! The fact that this question exists is a testament to that. Perhaps humans are not "naturally" good at logic...

@NaïmFavier really? Why is it a terrible formalism? I'm actually currently learning Natural Deduction as I was dissatisfied with my book's sequent calculus due to how unintuitive I found it.

Suppose $\Gamma \vdash \phi[t/x]$ where the constant $t$ does not occur free in $\Gamma$.
Since

$\Gamma \vdash \phi[t/x]$,

we have

$\Gamma, \exists x \neg \phi, \neg \phi [t/x] \vdash \phi[t/x]$.

But, we also have

$\Gamma,\exists x \neg \phi, \neg \phi[t/x] \vdash \neg \phi[t/x]$

So, we get

$\Gamma, \exists x \neg \phi, \neg \phi[t/x] \vdash \phi [t/x] \land \neg \phi [t/x]$.

Since explosion is not a primitive rule in your system, it bears proving, but I’m going to just assume it. Note that it follows from $\neg$-Elim.
So, we get

$\Gamma, \exists x \neg \phi, \neg [\phi t/x]\vdash \psi \land \neg \psi$

where $t$ does not occur in $\psi$.
Since $t$ does not occur free in any undischarged assumptions or in $\psi$, we can discharge $\neg \phi[t/x]$ and infer

$\Gamma, \exists x \neg \phi \vdash \psi \land \neg \psi$.

From the above, it follows that

$\Gamma, \exists x \neg \phi \vdash \psi$

and that

$\Gamma, \exists x \neg \phi \vdash \neg \psi$.

So, by $\neg$-Inrro, we get our desired result.

@MauroALLEGRANZA It follows by existential elimination. $\Gamma, \exists x \neg \phi, \neg \phi[t/x] \vdash \exists x \neg \phi$ and $\Gamma, \exists x \neg \phi, \neg \phi [t/x] \vdash \psi \land \neg \psi$ hold under the right conditions, which means we can conclude $\Gamma, \exists x \neg \phi \vdash \psi \land \neg \psi$. I don’t know how to format non-linear ND proofs, so I used sequents, but you can check the pdf OP listed in a comment for reference.

@MauroALLEGRANZA I admit my proof is messy and I could have done it closer to how OP’s text does it.

@MauroALLEGRANZA I’m not seeing the difficulty. The rule to prove is “If $\Gamma \vdash \phi [t/x]$ where $t$ does not occur in $\Gamma$, then infer $\Gamma \vdash \neg \exists \neg \phi$.” So, we can’t forget about $\Gamma$. In the arithmetic example, we don’t have $\Gamma \vdash \phi[t/x]$ unless $\Gamma$ entails that every number is even, which means it would have to be inconsistent itself. That’s beside the point.

I'm confused if this is a separate issue or not, but: once we reach $\Gamma, \exists x\neg \phi, \neg\phi[t/x]\vdash \psi\land\neg\psi$ how exactly can you conclude $\Gamma, \exists x\neg \phi\vdash \psi\land\neg\psi$?

@Sam check the existential Elim rule. If we have $\exists x \phi$ and a derivation of $\psi$ from $\phi [t/x]$ where $t$ is not in any assumptions or in $\psi$, we can infer $\psi$. You just have to set up your assumptions correctly.

Ok, forget my comments :-)

Just prove $\forall x \phi x \vdash \neg \exists x \neg \phi x$. If you continue the reasoning with the sequent, then you can use cut-elimination to get the desired result.
$$
\begin{array}{|l}
~~1.~~\forall x \phi(x) \hspace{15ex}\text{Premise}\\\hline
~~~~
\begin{array}{|l}
~~2.~~\exists x \neg \phi(x) \hspace{10ex}\text{SM}\neg I \\\hline
~~~~
\begin{array}{|l}
~~3.~~\neg \phi(t) \hspace{10ex}\text{SM}~\exists E,2 \\\hline
~~4.~~\phi(t) \hspace{11ex} \forall\mathrm E,1 \\
~~5.~~\bot \hspace{13ex} \bot\mathrm I,4,3 \\
\end{array} \\
~~6.~~\bot \hspace{16.5ex}\exists\mathsf E,3{-}5 \\
\end{array} \\
~~7.~~\neg \exists x \neg \phi(x) \hspace{11.5ex}\neg\mathrm I,2{-}6 \\
\end{array} \\
$$
Take the two sequents $\Gamma, \phi[t/x] \vdash \forall x \phi x$ (where $t$ does not appear in $\Gamma$, as the previous answer presumes), and $\forall x \phi x \vdash \neg \exists x \neg \phi x$, cut-eliminate them, and get $\Gamma, \phi[t/x] \vdash \neg \exists x \neg \phi x$. Ascend it to the status of a rule in your language, and you're done.
Additionally, if you also wanted to do this with $\forall E$ (with the caveat that you're admitting a classical semantics), you can just run the converse proof $\neg \exists x \neg \phi x \vdash \forall x \phi x$ and use $\Gamma, \forall x \phi x \vdash \phi[t/x]$ to get $\Gamma, \neg \exists x \neg \phi x \vdash \phi[t/x]$.
